# how to update a data to the database using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

```
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = 
           DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", 
           "system", "9900479852");
            Statement stmt =con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select *from registration where emailid='"+str+"' ");

             // here im fetching the emailid from data base
             while(rs.next()){

             emailId = rs.getString("emailId");
             mob = rs.getString("mobilenumber");
             System.out.println(emailId);

             //here we return update query`enter code here`
             if(emailId.equals(str)){
             stmt.executeQuery("update registration set password='"+s1+"' 
             where emailId='"+str+" '"); //query is executing but new vales are not updating to the data base
             p.println("updated");
             }
             con.close();    
             }
```

trying to update the data to the database i'm not able update ,sql query is executing but data is not updating to data base.

Comment: Follow a jpa or jdbc tutorial - your code is open sql injection attacks.  Also I believe you need to create a new stmt for the update, not re-use.

Comment: To run an update, use `executeUpdate()` not `executeQuery()`

Comment: i tired that alo it is not working

Comment: The problem is in the string concatenation of your update statement. You are putting an extra space after the email id. So if `s1` is abc and `str` is 123, then the SQL statement generated will be `update registration set password='abc'where emailId='123 '`. There is no record with that trailing space, so nothing gets updated. (Believe it or not, the lack of space before where is okay). Use a prepared statement like adityasrucitra suggested and you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code snippet, your code is trying to update database but indirectly fall into unnecessary process. Here is my correction, let say we have table (registration) in database consist of structure --> emailId (varchar 10), password (varchar 8).

Suppose you need to update 'registration', for each row when contain emailID = "gmail001" you'll set password to "myPassword". SQL statement for updating is `UPDATE registration SET password = "myPassword" WHERE emailId="gmail001"`

Back to your code, instead use 'Statement' class, you're prefer to use 'PreparedStatement' class for preconfigured SQL statement. Here is my corrections :

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "9900479852");
String sql = "UPDATE registration SET password=? WHERE emailID=?";
String newPassword = "myPassword";
String keyEmailId = "gmail001";

try{
    PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stat.setString(1, newPassword);
    stat.setString(2, keyEmailId);
    stat.executeUpdate();
}catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
} 
}
```

For more information please visit oracle javaSE tutorial for JDBC implementations --> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: but email id take  from cookie

Comment: just modify the code, change 'keyEmailId' to your emailid from your cookie source